# Doors dxl create link between modules

Tags: ibm-doors

i have the following issue and would like to ask for your help.

First of all, i am new to dxl and have never done that before.

I have 3 modules which are linked with each other.

Module 1 -> Module 2 -> Module 3

now we want to delete module 2 and do the direct link from module 1 to module 3.

How should i do this in dxl? We don't want to do it manually so i am trying to find out a way with dxl.

My idea is i will check for every objects in module 2 if each object in module 2 includes link 1 and 3 then connect 3 and 1 with eachother. But i don't know how the code look like. I have been searching it but there weren't so many infos about syntax and stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without DXL.

1. In Module 1 in exclusive edit mode, start the -> Analysis -> Wizard with the parameters:

   - Link direction: Out links
   - Link types: DOORS links
   - Select formal module: All modules
   - Select link module: All modules
   - attributes to display: Only Object Number
   - Width: any value is ok
   - Options: only one attribute per line
   - Recursive analysis: on
   - Multiple columns: on
   - depth of analysis: 2
   - Finish
2. You should now see two now columns. The column "Out-links at depth 2" shows the destination object that will be the link target of the new link to be created.
3. Start -> Tools -> Support Tools -> Convert Layout DXL to Attribute DXL, choose "Out-links at depth 2" -> Convert
4. Start -> Link -> Advanced -> Link by Attribute with the parameters:

   - Target Module: Module 3
   - Link Module: choose the Link module that you need
   - Existing attributes: choose "DXL for Out-links at depth 2"
   - Link direction: Source to target
   - Objects to be linked in target module: All Objects
   - OK
5. Now all links from Module 1 to Module 3 should be created. Check all created links thoroughly. Then delete Module 2

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!!! But in my case the column out links at depth 2 is empty. I guess because there is no throughout connection between the modules 1,2,3.How should i solve this? :(

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your situation correctly. Sorry, if I am too verbose or too simple here: I imagine that you have three modules, 1,2,3 and when you open the *current* version of Module 1, you see some objects that have an out link (red solid triangle). When you click on the triangle with the right mouse button of one of these Objects (say Object #234), you navigate to one object in the current version of Module 2 (say Object #345). Now, in this Object you have out- and in links (red and yellow solid triangles). Red triangle->right mouse button -> Module 3 Object #678.correct?

Comment: See https://i.imgur.com/0AuAa3r.png. Is this your situation? If not, how else?

Comment: However my column out links at depth 2 is empty

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you did not check "All modules" in the field "Target Module". Otherwise please post the code that has been generated for the second column. If "all modules" is not feasible because there are many other modules that you do not want to be considered, use  " open modules" and open modules 1,2 3 before the columns are created

Comment: I did, i figured out today that i did not have access to the module 3. That's why the column is empty. Now they give me only reading access to the module 3 and i tried to do it your way and i could tell that it didn't work.

Comment: You need a) write access to M1 to create links going out of M1 and to create the DXL Attribute. b) either write access to an existing link module or write access to a folder where a new link module shall reside. c) Write access to the folder where M1 is located to create a Link set from M1 to M3. d) perhaps admin access to that folder to change link access restrictions. I suggest that you first create one link from M1 to M3 manually, without DXL, to check whether you have all needed access rights. If it still does not work: which error message do you get, what exactly does not work?

Comment: I tried to do it without dxl i got following errors: https://ibb.co/252VJnz

Comment: If you could not open the link, the error is CRCRD5283I
- i do not have write access to source object ( which i have)
- do not have write access to target object 
-link modul does not exist ( it does)
- the mole was not a link module ( it is?)
-either the source or  the target modul is a descriptive module

now i am asking for writing access in the 3. modul in order to make it work 
Please help me out this problem, thank you very much !

Comment: You do not need write access to M3, but it won't hurt. I assume there is a link restriction. Open M1 and go to File→Module Properties→Linksets. Is the check box "Only allow outgoing links to the target modules in the above list" checked? If so, you need an entry "Target Module":M3, "Link Module":<your link mod>. Status can be mandatory or overridable. You need admin (a) rights in the containing folder to set this.

Comment: You will also need read access to the Link module. You will also need write access if (and only if) the link set has not been created. To check this: open the link module, click on the list of available link sets. If you want to, you can create a ink set manually (File→New→Linkset→Source=M1, Dest=M3). Typically, Link sets and Link restrictions are set up by the admins of your company

Comment: I have access to everything you mention. I tried it again and It's still not working and i have the same error. It will take days to clarify with my company about the link restriction since it's a big company. 

Is there another way to do the linking though? :(

Comment: that's really strange. Just to clarify: when you drag a new link from M1 to M3 or when you use (M1) Link→Start Link // (M3) Link→Make link from start, you get the error CRCRD5238I, and no other information about what happened?

Comment: And what about the Linkset restriction - is the checkox checked?

Comment: 1. no the error happened when i tried it with wizard.  
2. and then when i tried it manually, i was able to push M1 -> Start Link... but in M3  i was not able  to push the button (Make Link from start). 
3. I asked a colleague to try out with wizard as you told me but he got the same error as well ( he has access to everything except write access to m3)
4. The checkbox was not checked

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Well, M1 and the Link Module need to be prepared for creating links to M3 (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYQBZ_9.7.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/c_linksetpairings.html and the following pages, which also contain details about access rights you need). Either you have enough access rights yourself to prepare the modules or you have to ask this from your DOORS admins (after all, that's their job). It's now eleven days since you started the thread - by now the DOORS admins should have been able to set up the modules.